# How to pass dynamic values into an array

Tags: php, array

I'm creating a list of products, which is filtered to only show products within certain categories in Magento. I'm using the AddAttributeToFilter which is working fine:

```
$products->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array(105,106)));
```

This seems to work fine and it retrieves products that are in category 105 and 106.

However, I'm building a form that will dynamically pass the IDs into the filter depending on a user's selection. So in some case there will only be 2 category IDs, other times there maybe 6 different category IDs.

For example:

```
$products->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array(105,106,124,158,147)));
```

However, I can't figure out how I can create the array dynamically.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$val = "105,106,124,158,147";
$products->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array('$val')));
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you tried isn't an array, but a string.

Try this instead:

```
$val = "105,106,124,158,147";
$val_array = explode(",", $val);
$products->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array($val_array)));
```

The explode command will split the string by the comma and produce an array for it.

Comment: Wow, thanks that was super fast! Tried it out and it works perfectly. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)